# Unable to register VS express 2013 "SP324098: Your browser could not complete the operation."

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I have just install Visual Studio 2013 express edition and when I try to register it, it show a error message

> SP324098: Your browser could not complete the operation.

I have tried:

- Resetting IE settings
- Configured IE to allow cookies

But nothing works for me and the same error message keeps appearing.

I am able to login in Microsoft account in IE but not able to login into the  Microsoft account in VS.

Please help me to register my VS express offline online any way .

Comment: Possibly related: http://www.vb-magazin.de/forums/blogs/janm/archive/2014/05/17/sp324098-your-browser-could-not-complete-the-operation.aspx

Comment: Yes my system is in domain and i try it with connecting to VPN but still same error message appear , is there any offline way to get vs 2013 express register.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by signing out of my account and configuring the IE Trusted sites security level to Low.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now i uninstall VS 2013 and install VS 2012 express as 2012 is easy to register.